# Unable to pop back to view controller when using nib in xcode 5

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I am unable to pop back in xcode 5 using xib instead of storyboard.
I can push to view controller but unable to pop back to view controller
I am getting this error.:-
nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar.
Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.

Comment: Because maybe you are doint 2 animation at same time like pop and push same time with animation. Please check code. and also check you navigation stack like self.navigationcontroller.viewcontrollers.

Comment: Share some code. Code where you are doing the push and pop operation.

Comment: I am using this code for push-                                 HomeVC *homeObj=[[HomeVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"HomeVC" bundle:nil]; [self.navigationController pushViewController:homeObj animated:YES] and                     this code for pop -            [self.navigationController popToViewController:obj animated:YES];

Comment: From where you are pushing the view? For poping what are you doing?

Comment: I am using this code for poping -             [self.navigationController popToViewController:obj animated:YES];
 Making object of that class where to pop and simply poptoviewcontroller. I have also tried poptorootviewcontroller but unable to pop to vc

Comment: I am pushing from root view controller to second controller and poping from second view controller to root viewcontroller

Comment: I know that. Please share the two method where you write code for push and pop.

Comment: try this     [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];